# Why Are Programs Broken Down into Smaller Executables

Tags: design-patterns, ipc

Why are large programs broken into smaller programs?

There's not just Word.exe, there are multiple executables that I assume Word.exe calls. I can understand operating systems doing this in the case of terminal/command prompt. "Shutdown /f/s" calls the shutdown program, passes the argument then executes.

Going through my system apps on my rooted Galaxy S4, I see several programs that are used by the official camera app. One is called Best Face. Why is this separate and not just in the main camera.apk?

Are there better reasons? I'm relatively new to programming and I haven't started reading on design patterns yet, so maybe I'm asking this question prematurely.

I can see a few benefits such as RAM usage; only use what you need when you need it. 
I could also see this as a reason to better patch bugs and increase readability, but headers, like in the case of C++, provide this benefit.

I've looked this up, and the only answer I can seem to find answers dealing with breaking a program into separate files like Headers in C++.

Comment: Separate address space...

Comment: @ta.speot.is Because of RAM limitations of a 32bit computer?

Comment: Primarily because one application can't access another's memory by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a solution to solve specific problems. Here are a few examples:

1. By design, your application have to be distributed because it needs to run on more than one computers communicating through the network (for example, client/server application). Therefore, you need several different process running in different computers. However, it don't mean that your computer can't host several of such processes. The point is just that by design you just need to separate different parts of your application so that each part can be running anywhere as long as it's accessible (through network or IPC). Examples: debuggers, IDEs launching compilers, client/server applications (like some games which run a server locally in solo), C/C++ compilers (which often fork themselve for each compilation unit to be compiled in concurrently), etc.
2. You need to isolate the failure of each different process. If one process fails, you might no be able to do anything from the process itself to try to fix it or to manage the failure in any way. Therefore you need a separate process that "monitors" the other process. IF one process die, it don't kill the other processes. That's for example how is designed Chrome (the internet browser): each tab is a process. That way, if something goes wrong with executing a web page, the whole tab can even crash, it will not kill all the tabs at once, as it was doing before with other browsers (which since then adopted similar strategies). Basically, sandboxing. Also see: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/202089/chromes-multiple-process-per-each-tabs
3. Memory limitation: if your target computer is 32bit, and you can easily get reach the memory address limitations this imply, then you'll need to splitt your application into several processes so that each process have it's own address space. I'm not totally sure but I think I've read somewhere that Visual Studio (which is still a 32bit executable) also use a lot of different processes for this very reason (among other things). Of course the problem is less important when you can use 64bit exclusively, but not everyone have this luxury yet.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are several reasons, some of them you've already figured out yourself, like memory.

Smaller programs that perform less tasks are easier to develop, test, maintain.

You don't want to break a whole system just because someone introduced a bug into a small part of it. Like putting all the eggs in the same place.

Also, consider that many programs/systems are developed by different teams and these projects start/stop at different times.

Sometimes, you have an app that have parallel development source code branches, because the next software release cannot wait for the previous one to start because of time to market.

And if they are small and self contained, with a well defined function, they can be combined to solve more complex things. (see "The Pragmatic Programmer: From Journeyman to Master" book about UNIX tools).

And you also may want to extends some program functionality, so you still have plug-ability... how would you do this in a monolithic thing?

Comment: I'm still a novice, and in high school, and I didn't think about the fact that many programs are broken up and teams write them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad field, in which having multiple executables is only one aspect. It all comes down to managing complexity.

The CPU, be it on a server, desktop computer or smart phone, processes instructions that it reads from memory, without having an idea of executables. If complexity wasn't an issue in software development, the way in which the instructions are delivered to the CPU probably would not involve executables. In the beginning of the computer age, computers were programmed by directly manipulating the memory by hand - literally by pushing switches. If there was a task the computer had to do, it was programmed this way.

Later, [boot loaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting) gave human operators the opportunity to selectively load instructions into the memory, for example from punch cards or magnetic tape. Now, programs could be stored outside of the computer and be reused. In a way, those were the first executables.

As processing power, memory and storage space grew, there had to be a system to manage all these resources and so operating systems were developed. Now operators of a computer did not need to manage the punch cards and magnetic tapes themselves. Those programs were now available on a file system. A file that could be loaded into memory and run was an executable. Running a task was simply done by instructing the operating system to execute the file.

Now, having the opportunity to manage their programs as files on a file system, operators were able to link the usage of executables together, to build more complex applications. This way, single executables were able to be reused for different applications. It also made other things possible, described in the other answers to your question.

These principles of operating and file systems are still in place today, on your computer or smart phone. It all began when computer operators looked for a way to program a computer without pushing switches.